# Creating the wp-config.php file manually

Tags: wp-config

Setting up WordPress, I'm getting the following message:

"Sorry, but I can't write the wp-config.php file.
"You can create the wp-config.php manually and paste the following text into it."

1. Do I copy-paste the text into a file and upload that to the server?
2. If yes to question 1, to create the file, is Text Wrangler an appropriate program to use? (I use a Mac)
3. If Text Wrangler is an appropriate program, in saving the file, would I choose "Line breaks: Unix (LF)" and "Encoding: Unicode (UTF-8)" and would I manually add ".php" to the file name when I save it?
4. The text that WordPress is giving me to paste into wp-config.php includes comments such as:

> *
>   * This file is used by the wp-config.php creation script during the
>   * installation. You don't have to use the web site, you can just copy this file
>   * to "wp-config.php" and fill in the values."

and:

> /**#@+
>   * Authentication Unique Keys and Salts.
>   *
>   * Change these to different unique phrases!
>   * You can generate these using the {@link https://api.wordpress.org/secret-key/1.1>/salt/ WordPress.org secret-key service}
>   * You can change these at any point in time to invalidate all existing cookies. This >will force all users to have to log in again.

...do I just copy all this into the file wp-config.php and upload it to the server?

Thanks, Richard

Comment: also, do i upload wp-config.php to public_html  ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is how you make your config.php manually:

In your download there should be a wp-config-sample.php.

1. Open this is a text editor.
2. Fill in your database connection details.
3. Go to https://api.wordpress.org/secret-key/1.1/salt/ and get the code.
4. Copy the above cope and paste into the sample file over the top of the existing `defines`
5. Save the file as wp-config.php

The answer to "should I put it in public_html?" is yes if thats where the rest of your wordpress files are.